Extendible vector field
I'm given the following problem:
Let $\sigma \colon I \rightarrow M$ be a smooth curve and $t_0 \in I$ such that $\sigma'(t_0) \neq 0$. Then there exists an open interval $J \subseteq I$ such that for every vector field $X$ along $\sigma_{|J}$ (that is, $X \colon J \rightarrow TM$ with $X(t) \in T_{\sigma(t)}M$), $X$ is extendible (that is, there exists a neighborhood of $\sigma(J)$, U, and a vector field $Y$ on $U$ such that $Y_{\sigma(t)} = X(t)$ for each $t$ in $J$).
Since $\sigma'(t_0) \neq 0$, there exists $J$ such that $\sigma_{|J}$ is an embedding. Now if $\sigma(J)$ were closed, I could extend the vector field $Y$ on $\sigma(J)$ defined by $Y(p) = X(\sigma^{-1}(p))$. However this is not the case, hence I'm at a loss. Any help?

This is a local question. The normal bundle of a small segment of $\sigma$ is trivial.
